# Store Bookmarks Chrome Online

Tags: bookmark

I use Chrome as my primary web browser on my laptop but would like them to be automatically(all bookmarks) to be published online for others to view.

Is there an application service that does this automatically.  Chrome used to publish them in your profile but no longer does this unfortunately.

Comment: Whom do you want the bookmarks "published" to? For sharing with Team Members or for public use?

Comment: @YisroelTech public is fine or team members

Comment: How many people? (there are some solutions that limit the amount of people for free)

Comment: @Yisroel at least five but I would prefer public

Comment: I thought I know of some options, but after taking a look they do not meet your requirements. Most of them are either you can share bookmarks that you create and manage with them or the most it'll allow you to manually export and upload the Chome Bookmarks HTML. The closest is https://teamsyncbookmarks.com/index.html

Answer (score -2):

If you use the Bookmarks bar, you can use a special type of bookmark called a bookmarklet that will bring a popup to post pages onto Google+. According to the [Google Plus documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink-bookmarklet), you can autopost pages by highlighting and dragging the following to your bookmarks bar and clicking it when you want to post it

> javascript:void(window.open(%27https://plus.google.com/share%3Fur%5Cl%3D%27%2BencodeURIComponent(location), %27Share to Google%2B%27,%27width%3D600,height%3D460,menubar%3Dno,location%3Dno,status%3Dno%27))%3B

Comment: I want my entire bookmarks bar published.  This is hardly a solution for that.

Comment: That's far from "automatically publishing all bookmarks". Imagine William having 1000+ bookmarks already stored; would you suggest to draw each of them manually on the bookmarklet?